# How to remove a payment option from onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, theme

In onepage checkout page , there is a field called "Payment Information". 
I want to remove the first option as shown in screenshot "Credit Card / Visa, Mastercard, AMEX, JCB, Diners" . 
[image] 
I've searched all the files in magento folders such as :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Payment
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php
app/design/frontend/base/default/...
```

But no luck ! I couldn't find any file containing the text I've just mentioned.
I've also searched all of admin configuration pages & didn't find anything.
Could someone please help me on removing this option from onepage checkout page ?

Answer (score 2):

Just goto /Admin

```
System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods. Disable it from there.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot find it in the templates is because this information is pulled out of the `core_config_data` table and presented by the templates. You remove it by disabling the payment method in System Config, not by editing templates.

Navigate to System => Configuration => Payment Methods and look for the window shade that contains the unwanted method in its title text field. Change `Enabled` to `No`, flush cache and the method should disappear from the shopping cart

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on it , Finally I got the answer !
It was @

```
System -> Configuration -> Moneybookers
```